# Parse a command line string into flags and arguments in Golang

Tags: go, arguments, package, command-line-arguments, flags

I'm looking for a package that would take a string such as `-v --format "some example" -i test` and parse it into a slice of strings, handling quotes, spaces, etc. properly:

```
-v
--format
some example
-i
test
```

I've checked the built-in `flag` package as well as other flag handling packages on Github but none of them seem to handle this particular case of parsing a raw string into tokens. Before trying to do it myself I'd rather look for a package as I'm sure there are a lot of special cases to handle.

Any suggestion?

Comment: This is a mixture of what the shell does (the quoted string grouping) and the particular behavior of gnu option parsing tools (the interspersed args and flags, and different long/short flag format). I'm not aware of anyone combining these into a package.

Comment: A quick hack (if you are flexible to change the way you provide the input) would be (please see `flag` package's documentation):  

 set := &flag.FlagSet{}
 
 v := set.Bool("v", false, "")
 format := set.String("format", "", "")
 i := set.String("i", "", "")
 
 set.Parse([]string{`-v`, `--format="some example"`, `-i=test`})
 for k, v := range set.Args() {
  log.Println(k, v)
 }
 
 log.Printf("v=%v format=%v i=%v", *v, *format, *i)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. Are you planning on doing something like: `cmd -v --format "some example" -i test`? If so, you could just grab all of the arguments from `os.Args`.

Comment: I don't know how that question could have attracted "opinionated answers and spam", as it's a specific problem, which would require a specific answer. Anyway I couldn't find any package so I've ended up doing it myself. Solution is there: https://github.com/laurent22/massren/blob/ae4c57da1e09a95d9383f7eb645a9f69790dec6c/main.go#L172

Comment: @this.lau_ take a look at [go-getoptions](https://github.com/DavidGamba/go-getoptions), I needed extra flexibility. Using `opt.SetUnknownMode("pass")` will leave things as you want them in the `remaining` slice.

Comment: @this.lau_: Super useful for me. Thanks for posting a link to your codebase for massren :]

Comment: @this.lau_ also useful for me, thanks! Though I modified example a bit to iterate over runes in string (not bytes) to handle unicode

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For information, this is the function I've ended up creating.

It splits a command into its arguments. For example, `cat -v "some file.txt"`, will return `["cat", "-v", "some file.txt"]`.

It also correctly handles escaped characters, spaces in particular. So `cat -v some\ file.txt` will also correctly be split into `["cat", "-v", "some file.txt"]`

```
func parseCommandLine(command string) ([]string, error) {
    var args []string
    state := "start"
    current := ""
    quote := "\""
    escapeNext := true
    for i := 0; i < len(command); i++ {
        c := command[i]

        if state == "quotes" {
            if string(c) != quote {
                current += string(c)
            } else {
                args = append(args, current)
                current = ""
                state = "start"
            }
            continue
        }

        if (escapeNext) {
            current += string(c)
            escapeNext = false
            continue
        }

        if (c == '\\') {
            escapeNext = true
            continue
        }

        if c == '"' || c == '\'' {
            state = "quotes"
            quote = string(c)
            continue
        }

        if state == "arg" {
            if c == ' ' || c == '\t' {
                args = append(args, current)
                current = ""
                state = "start"
            } else {
                current += string(c)
            }
            continue
        }

        if c != ' ' && c != '\t' {
            state = "arg"
            current += string(c)
        }
    }

    if state == "quotes" {
        return []string{}, errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("Unclosed quote in command line: %s", command))
    }

    if current != "" {
        args = append(args, current)
    }

    return args, nil
}
```

Comment: this will make an error if command starts with "

Answer (score 15):

Looks similar to [shlex](https://godoc.org/github.com/google/shlex):

```
import "github.com/google/shlex"
shlex.Split("one \"two three\" four") -> []string{"one", "two three", "four"}
```

Comment: Should be the official answer.

Answer (score 5):

If the args were passed to your program on the command line then the shell should handle this and `os.Args` will be populated correctly. For example, in your case `os.Args[1:]` will equal

```
[]string{"-v", "--format", "some example", "-i", "test"}
```

If you just have the string though, for some reason, and you'd like to mimic what the shell would do with it, then I recommend a package like https://github.com/kballard/go-shellquote

Answer (score 2):

@laurent 's answer is wonderful, but it doesn't work when `command` includes utf-8 char.

It fail the third test:

```golang
func TestParseCommandLine(t *testing.T){
    tests := []struct{
        name string
        input string
        want []string
    }{
        {
            "normal",
            "hello world",
            []string{"hello", "world"},
        },
        {
            "quote",
            "hello \"world hello\"",
            []string{"hello", "world hello"},
        },
        {
            "utf-8",
            "hello 世界",
            []string{"hello", "世界"},
        },
        {
            "space",
            "hello\\ world",
            []string{"hello world"},
        },
    }
    for _, tt := range tests{
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            got, _ := parseCommandLine(tt.input)
            if !reflect.DeepEqual(got, tt.want){
                t.Errorf("expect %v, got %v", tt.want, got)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Based on his/her answer, i wrote this func that works good for utf-8, just by replacing `for i := 0; i < len(command); i++ {c := command[i]` to `for _, c := range command`

Here's the my answer:

```golang
func parseCommandLine(command string) ([]string, error) {
    var args []string
    state := "start"
    current := ""
    quote := "\""
    escapeNext := true
    for _, c := range command {

        if state == "quotes" {
            if string(c) != quote {
                current += string(c)
            } else {
                args = append(args, current)
                current = ""
                state = "start"
            }
            continue
        }

        if escapeNext {
            current += string(c)
            escapeNext = false
            continue
        }

        if c == '\\' {
            escapeNext = true
            continue
        }

        if c == '"' || c == '\'' {
            state = "quotes"
            quote = string(c)
            continue
        }

        if state == "arg" {
            if c == ' ' || c == '\t' {
                args = append(args, current)
                current = ""
                state = "start"
            } else {
                current += string(c)
            }
            continue
        }

        if c != ' ' && c != '\t' {
            state = "arg"
            current += string(c)
        }
    }

    if state == "quotes" {
        return []string{}, errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("Unclosed quote in command line: %s", command))
    }

    if current != "" {
        args = append(args, current)
    }

    return args, nil
}
```

Comment: brave but not convincing.

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин should I make some further updates for making it more convincing?

Comment: No, it makes enough sense the way it is and is clearly an improvement, for which you deserve +1.  Anyway, I think I would update the other answer

Answer (score 0):

[hedzr/cmdr](https://github.com/hedzr/cmdr) might be good. it's a getopt-like command-line parser, light weight, fluent api or classical style.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but might be still relevant. What about using regex? It is quite simple and might be enough for most of cases:

```golang
r := regexp.MustCompile(`\"[^\"]+\"|\S+`)
m := r.FindAllString(`-v --format "some example" -i test`, -1)
fmt.Printf("%q", m)
// Prints out ["-v" "--format" "\"some example\"" "-i" "test"]
```

You can try https://go.dev/play/p/1K0MlsOUzQI

**Edit:**

To handle also `test\ abc` to be a 1 entry, use this regex: `\"[^\"]+\"|\S+\\\s\S+|\S+`

Comment: I wouldn't recommend rolling your own arg parsing manually....